# Heap Dump Analysis - Find root cause of OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I am running an application that has 4 gigs of maxmimum heap size `-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -Xmn1024m` with GC configured as `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50` and GC interval of `Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=43200000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=43200000`

Suddenly my application went to heap out of memory exception and i took thread dumps and heap dumps on the same occasion. On analyzing Thread dumps, thread are stuck due to creating some value to a hashMap and arrayList. ByteArrayOutStream has created locks in one of the thread.

On Analysing Heap dump in eclipse memory analyzer tool, it clearly says bytearray object has occupied almost 1 Gigs of Heap. From the GCViewer it shows it has a peak in fraction of second. I am clue less why suddenly Byte array object used 1 Gigs of space. Can some one help me out to narrow down the culprit.

-- Application Server - Weblogic 12c

Comment: It's hard to say anything with provided information. Can you show more details about your consuming memory code?

Comment: Just knowing it's a byte array won't help you much. You'll have to look which of the objects of your application is using the array to have any clue as to what went wrong. MAT does allow you to move up the hierarchy to the containing object.

Comment: more code detail would be helpful, running a default application with provided jvm flags doesn't replicate anything for me

Comment: @NickBell What are all the additional information you required on this

Answer (score 1):

> On Analysing Heap dump in eclipse memory analyzer tool, it clearly says bytearray object has occupied almost 1 Gigs of Heap.

Use the shortest paths to GC root feature of MAT to see which references are holding onto that byte array.

Comment: I tried with Merger Shortest Path to GC roots with all reference is not showing any reference. I tried with Dominator tree, it shows me the byt array objcet with memory address "0x74d407870" and certain values in byte []. Other than this, any other way?

Comment: it's possible that the object becomes unreachable after being allocated due to the OOME. Maybe you're trying to serialize something large into the ByteArrayOutStream, which of course would be held in memory until it is used.

Comment: You are correct.Am trying to serialize an object. From the JVisualVM,  i can see the reference, ` this (Java frame)     - value: byte[] #65581 (1,073,790,734 items)
 <- buf (Java frame)     - class: java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream, value: byte[] #65581 (1,073,790,734 items)
  <- out (Java frame)     - class: java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream, value: java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream #12
   <- bout (Java frame)     - class: com.terracotta.toolkit.object.serialization.SerializationStrategyImpl$SerializerObjectOutputStream, value: java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream #13`

Comment: then either bump the memory limit or serialize into a file